# iOS8: class size w:Regular h:Compact To w:Any h:Any

Tags: ios, storyboard, size-classes

I've made my storyboard support only w:Regular h:Compact.

Cause i needed to support all devices in landscape.

But I've figure that it's not supporting iPad that way.

When i run iPad it just a blank page.

I tried to convert it to any:any but it hide all the sub views.
Is there anyway to convert this class size to any:any to support all without risking redo all this work?
Or at least I need a way to make it only for iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, **wRegular hCompact** is for iPhone 6 Plus in landscape, not iPads in landscape:

[image]

Be sure to check the description at the bottom of the size class choice.

If you want to convert existing elements to show in **wAny hAny**, try choosing each element, then going to the attributes inspector and clicking the + button at the bottom, then add it for any width and any height. Make sure the checkmark is there beside installed for any width and any height also.

[image]

Comment: ok i've tried that but the thing is .. when i choose any width beside installed .. the option of any height is disabled

should I make this step after i change the whole storyboard to any:any or before that

Comment: hmmm I thought if the other any option was disabled after choosing the first one it meant that you were using any,any already